# Do I need to manually defrag a Windows 7 PC?

Tags: windows-7, defragment

Given that Windows 7 will auto defrag a PC when it's idle, does that mean manually defragging a PC is a thing of the past?

Answer (score 8):

Windows 7, by default, sets up a schedule to defrag the hard drive.  You can modify the schedule by opening `Disk Deframenter` (type `defrag` in the search box in the start menu).

Generally, I find that the Disk Defragmenter always shows 0% for all my drives, meaning that Windows is doing its job to keep the drives defragmented.  Generally I would say it's not necessary to run a manual defrag, though you may want to run a third-party defrag like [MyDefrag](http://www.mydefrag.com/) if you want to re-organize the files on the disk, like putting large files at the end of the drive.

Personally, I never worry about it and just let the scheduled task do it's thing.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, Windows 7 does a very good job of defragmenting for you in the background.  However, if you work with large files or files that grow (or a combination, if you run virtual machines for example), or your hard drive is getting full, then you will need to defragment manually once in a while.  I work with virtual machines a lot and due to the size of the drive in my computer, I primarily use expanding disk images, so once my drive was over 70% full I started seeing a lot of fragmentation.

So if you have more than 40% free on your hard drive, don't worry about it, just check it once in a while, but if you have less than that, especially less than 20%, you might have some big fragmentation issues.

Answer (score 1):

You don't if you leave it on 24/7.

However, if it's like a laptop and is rarely if ever idle while it's on, then it's a good idea to run a manual defrag because it'll rarely get a chance to automatically do so.

Comment: I agree with this, 4 of my 6 machines are laptops and they always show "never" in defragmented status so I run those manually.